# Syntax error in C

Tags: c, enums

```
 5 enum state {ST_BEFORE_KEY, ST_IN_KEY, ST_BEFORE_VALUE, ST_TERM, ST_ERR};
  6 
  7 typedef struct {
  8   state st;
      ...
```

The above code reports :

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘state’
```

What's wrong here in using enum type?

Answer (score 9):

Use `enum state` or include `typedef enum state state`.

Enumeration tags are in a different namespace in C than identifiers (variables, functions or typedefs).

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
enum state {ST_BEFORE_KEY, ST_IN_KEY, ST_BEFORE_VALUE, ST_TERM, ST_ERR};

typedef struct {
    enum state st;
    ...
};
```

Marginally linked to this [FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/struct/impltypedef.html). And here's a discussion on [namespaces](http://c-faq.com/decl/namespace.html).

There are four different kinds of namespaces, for:

- labels (i.e. goto targets);
- **tags** (names of structures, unions,
  and enumerations; these three aren't
  separate even though they
  theoretically could be);
- structure/union members (one
  namespace per structure or union);
  and
- **everything else** (functions,
  variables, **typedef names**, enumeration
  constants), termed ``ordinary
  identifiers'' by the Standard.

**EDIT**

Since the OP is asking for an example..

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
    int foo;
};

struct bar {
    int foo;
    struct foo bar;
};
```

Comment: isn't the `3rd` duplicate with `2nd`?

Comment: @R__ No, it isn't. Read more carefully: "structure **names**" vs "structure **members**".

Comment: oh I see.But can you give an example that shows structure members are in a separate namespace? I've never known it before.

Comment: @R__ Added a convoluted example. Wouldn't know what to make of it :))

Comment: but that doesn't show structure **member** is in a different namespace than outside.

Comment: @R__ I can see four members in that example. Perhaps we have different understandings on what a "member" constitutes ?

Comment: why 4,shouldn't it be `2`? Namely `foo` of type `int` and `bar` of type `struct foo`?

Comment: @R__ Each of your comments here is wrong. I suggest that you spend some time a) learning C and b) learning to read and comprehend what people write.

Answer (score 2):

If you use c++, it is ok;

on c ( not c++) you should write like this.

```
5 enum state {ST_BEFORE_KEY, ST_IN_KEY, ST_BEFORE_VALUE, ST_TERM, ST_ERR};
6 
7 typedef struct {
8   enum state st;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
typedef struct {
    enum state st;
```